# Laravel Spatial error on save or retrieve

Tags: laravel-8, spatial

My code was working fine and all of the sudden I'm getting a real strange error. (really all of the sudden! I didn't change a line of code! Only my mac got updated to latest version which I honestly don't see how that could be an issue!)

When I try to save or retrieve any entity that has a point data type in it I get this exception:

PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of JsonSerializable: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point::jsonSerialize() should either be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/amirpeivandi/Projects/nwrewards/vendor/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/src/Types/Point.php:93

Any idea what this could be?

Amir

Answer (score 1):

You should ask Package Developer to fix this error, and update your package to new version

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error is caused by failing to add the spatial trait and  protected spatial field to the model.

```
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\SpatialTrait;

class User
{
    use SpatialTrait;

    protected $spatialFields = [
        'location',
    ];
}
```

You can read about this requirement on GitHub [here](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial#create-a-model).